# The best way to extract all unicode text in a PDF file in .Net?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp 5.1.1 to extract all text to count all words in it with the following code

```
public static string GetTextFromAllPages(String pdfPath)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter(); 
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) 
        output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));

    return output.ToString();
}
```

but for different languages(en,fr,..) and inputs files it mostly gives wrong result from real value i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp  (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) has a robust API for manipulating pdf's.

Comment: But does it let you count words, paragraphs and lines in PDF files? I think you'll find the answer is... no.

Comment: I think that the itextsharp is not capable of counting, but  not sure yet